# Parsing XML file in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.android

I am fairly new to developing for android using Xamarin.

I am making an application that translates dietary requirements into other languages and I am trying to load the options that one can input when making a translation.

To do this the text is put into a list after I have read the XML file:

```
            XmlDocument LifeStyles = new XmlDocument();
            LifeStyles.Load("engLifestyles.xml");
```

and the xml is located here: 
[File Location In Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf2N4.png)

However i keep getting this error where the file is named when i run the app:

Unhandled Exception:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/engLifestyles.xml". occurred.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Need full pathname  of xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xamarin.Android project you have to save your file in `Assets` folder, then you can load it. `Assets` folder in Xamarin is way to include arbitary files like text, xml, music etc.

> Asstes folder files are readonly so if you try to write to your xml file you will get `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`

So your code should look like this:

```
XmlDocument LifeStyles = XmlDocument.Load(Assets.Open("engLifestyles.xml"));
```

or you can use `AssetsManager` too:

```
 AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
 XmlDocument LifeStyles = XmlDocument.Load(assets .Open("engLifestyles.xml"));
```

Comment: For your first suggestion do I put that code under the new xml declaration?

Comment: You have to move your file `engLifestyles.xml` into `Assets` folder.

Comment: I have put the xml file into assets and put in the following code:
           `XmlDocument LifeStyles = new XmlDocument();
           LifeStyles.Load(Assets.Open("engLifestyles.xml"));`

But now i get this error on the second line:
Unhandled Exception:

Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: engLifestyles.xml occurred

Comment: string content;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (Assets.Open ("engLifestyles.xml")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
doc.LoadXml (content);  - try that

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: engLifestyles.xml occurred
still got the same error

Comment: Upload your project on github or somewhere Dropbox I will take a look

Comment: It worked! I had the build option to something that wasn't android assets thank you so much ^_^ this problem has been bugging me for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I ended up using. First, place the xml file into the Assets directory. Open it's properties and mark it's `Build Action` as `AndroidAsset`. Mark it's `Copy to Output Directory` as `Copy if newer` or some such. These will ensure your xml file is readable and is shipped with your package.

After all of that, you can then do this. In my case I wanted to load a bunch of strings into a dictionary.

```
    private async void LoadStrings()
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(STRING_FILE))
            {
                XmlDocument localInfo_Xml = new XmlDocument();
                localInfo_Xml.Load(stream);
                XmlNodeList tagList = localInfo_Xml.GetElementsByTagName(STRING_KEY);
                foreach (XmlElement xmlElement in tagList)
                {
                    string name = xmlElement.GetAttribute(NAME_KEY);
                    string value = xmlElement.InnerText;
                    strings.Add(name, value);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Hope that helps someone else's day get better.